# Assign to dynamic variable name in Bash

Tags: linux, shell, unix

How do I assign a value to variable that has a variable in its name?

```
var1="file"
var2_$var1="folder"
```

The code above gives me the error `-bash: var2_file=folder: command not found`. I was curious to know how to assign to a variable with another variable in its name.

Version of Bash is "GNU bash, version 4.1.2"

Comment: This is very shell specific. What shell are you using? Bash (from the error message)? Please list the version as well. Do not respond in a comment. Please edit the question itself.

Comment: Why do you need it? There might be better ways to achieve your goal.

Comment: In 99% cases is better idea to use associative arrays.

Comment: [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) covers this in detail -- both associative arrays *and* indirect assignment as such.

Answer (score 5):

With `bash` you can use `declare`:

```
declare var2_$var1="123"
```

Comment: Would `export` work the same way? What about `set`?

Comment: Thanks alot for both of your answers. I tried `export`, `set` and `declare` all worked fine. But know how to retrieve value of it.!!

`echo $var2_$var1`
The output of it should be "123"

Comment: Yes, that's the problem with this approach. I recomend to use and assoc array instead

Answer (score 0):

How about using another variable to hold the dynamic name and use it for retrieving the value after setting?

```
new_var=var2_$var1
declare var2_$var1="123"
echo "${!new_var}" # => 123
```

Unfortunately, Bash doesn't allow `declare $new_var="123"` - that would have made this a little prettier.